# how to get average age from sql date field in c#

Tags: c#, sql, date, average

I have database and one birthday field with date type. I have to find average age, max age and min age abouth their birthday in c#. Can you help me?

Comment: And **what database** (and which version) are you using? SQL is just the query language...

Comment: -1. Stack Overflow is here to help you help yourself, not write the code for you. Do you know how to retrieve the date of birth from the database? If no, there's plenty of info on the web. Then calculate the age for each person - again, easy and well documented. Finally, calculate the averages you require. If I'm being harsh and in fact you have code and it doesn't work, please post the code and details of what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the following SQL queries:

```
SELECT MIN(age_columnName) FROM TableName;

SELECT MAX(age_columnName) FROM TableName;

SELECT AVG(age_columnName) FROM TableName;
```

You need to use these queries in your c# code, something like this:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
//
    // First access the connection string, which may be autogenerated in Visual Studio for you.
    //
    string connectionString = "connection string"
    //
    // In a using statement, acquire the SqlConnection as a resource.
    //
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        //
        // Open the SqlConnection.
        //
        con.Open();
        //
        // The following code shows how you can use an SqlCommand based on the SqlConnection.
        //
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT AVG(age_columnName) FROM TableName", con))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // process it
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since OP only has birthdate, need to compare today's date to birthdate to get age.

Answer (score 1):

Date and time functions are specific to databases.  The following shows how to do this in SQL Server:

```
select avg(cast(datediff(year, birthdate, getdate()) as float)) as avg_age,
       min(datediff(year, birthdate, getdate())) as min_age,
       max(datediff(year, birthdate, getdate())) as max_age
```

All databases have similar functions, but they might have different names or somewhat different syntax.  The `cast( . . . to float)` is because SQL Server does integer averages of integer values.  Some databases would produce a floating point average without the cast.

The `getdate()` function also differs among databases -- `now()`, `sysdate()`, `CURRENT_DATETIME`, for instance.